# Aluminum Splicer/Reducer for Connecting Thicker Aluminum and Copper Wires

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, code-compliance, connectors, aluminum-wiring

I would like to connect 6 gauge aluminum wire to 12 gauge copper wire.   Is an aluminum splicer/reducer suitable for this in the USA?  An example is the Morris 90612.   It is a rectangular aluminum block with holes on the ends to accept the wires that are then held down by screws.  It of course requires antioxidant and insulation, probably rubber and vinyl electrical tape.

There is much discussion about Al to Cu connections here and elsewhere on the web, but the common solutions either don't handle 6 gauge or are in my opinion overpriced for the task.  Split bolts are another option, but I wanted to avoid the awkward shape, especially when it comes to insulating.

I think the item I am a referring to has been mentioned here as something like a mechanical lug.  It almost seems like a slam-dunk that it is suitable since it is AL9CU dual rated, but there are many things that might not be obvious in the rules.  In the Q&A section at one of the big box store websites,  a customer service rep said another brand nearly identical and also AL9CU was not rated for this.   The only reason I could think of is if the wires are inserted too far and become intermixed.  Some versions are said to isolate the two sides.

This is to make a pigtail to connect the 6 gauge aluminum to a 20 amp breaker with an 8 gauge maximum.  The splice would be in the breaker panel, which has plenty of open space.  The old 40 amp breaker is beyond the required maximum overcurrent protection for a new heat pump.

I could avoid the whole aluminum to copper thing if thinner aluminum wire were readily available for the pigtail.  I don't want to go to the effort of trying to replace the wire all the way out to the heat pump.

Sorry so long-winded, but I think of what might be misunderstood and add detail.  Thanks for reading and all the past answers I read.

EDIT:  Morris tech support told me not to use 90612 for this.  Details in comments below.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Code requires an outside disconnect for any heat pump. *Code doesn't care what kind you use*.  One option is to leave the 40A breaker in the panel, and use a "2 space subpanel" style of disconnect with a 20A breaker in it.  That will also take care of the Cu/Al splicing for you :)

Comment: There is already an outside disconnect.  The original oversized and inefficient 3 ton  condenser is replaced with a 1.5 ton, thus the reduction in breaker amperage. 
 Considered replacing it with fusible type, but too costly.   Subpanel is the same thing.  Thanks for the additional idea.

Comment: When I say too costly, it is from the standpoint of being off by just one gauge on the breaker.   Your idea made quite a bit of sense if it were not a replacement heat pump.

Comment: A subpanel and breaker will very likely cost less than suitable connectors, and suits the replacement heat pump perfectly.

Comment: It is free advice, but I don't see anyone saying there is a rule against the "lugs" I asked about.  I will look more at the MAC 6-18 and subpanel but am satisfied with having to insulate lugs if they are not a rule violation.  The rubber/vinyl electrical tapes seem to be standard practice for split bolts.  I like to do things right, but I prefer not to spend/do more than I need.  However, I don't want to create a worse situation than running the compressor on a slightly oversized breaker or ignoring the broken strand that allows a 6 gauge wire to fit in an 8 gauge hole.

Comment: @HHH If you're confident you can do a competent tape-wrap insulation job, that's between you and your inspector. This site is widely read, and I am reluctant to openly advise any random reader to do that.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Some kind of UL heat shrink is another insulating option I was thinking about.  I initially thought it would make it hard to inspect what was beneath.  Also thought difficult to get a piece big enough for the lug to shrink enough to grab the thinner wire, but by my logic it just needs to keep anything from touching the bare metal.  Not sure my logic is adequate.

Comment: @HHH yeah, I'm reluctant to propose a wrap job, especially an irreversible one, because the inspector may want to know or see that you torqued it to spec with a torque tool per NEC 110.14. That is the #1 error when doing screw connections.

Comment: I asked Morris tech support about the 90612 lug.  He said they do not make any product to splice aluminum to copper and dual rated means copper to copper or aluminum to aluminum.  He referred me to AlumiConn, though that does not cover the 6 AWG wire I told him I was using.   Morris sells things that look like the Polaris, and its website has a split bolt that is described as UL listed for Aluminum to Copper.  Despite these inconsistencies in his response, I decided there is too much doubt for me to use these lugs.  Will likely use split bolts.   3 local supply shops did not have MAC 618's.

Comment: @HHH -- that is *very* strange that an Al/Cu rated multiport connector can't handle a copper wire in one hole and an aluminum wire in a different hole

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- Reading UL 486a to try to see if it says what a dual rating means and there is some talk about cu to cu and al to al meaning two or more of these conductors in an opening and "cu to al, intermixed" being in the same opening so maybe tech support thought I meant I wanted to splice by cramming both wires in one of the two holes.  I did say I planned to take care not to intermix dissimilar metals.  Now that I look at split bolts, I am also seeing confusing things, like the descriptor may say for all combinations of al, cu, steel, etc. but then say UL 486A Copper only.

Comment: @HHH -- I'd ignore split bolt stuff, that's a different world

Answer (score 8):

### You need a disconnect out at the outdoor unit.

NEC isn't particular about *what kind* you use.  If you want to use a pullout disconnect, hunky dory.  A big knife switch disconnect, fine.  A "2 space subpanel" with a 20A breaker in it, also acceptable.

Did you catch that last one where the disconnect **has a 20A breaker in it**? :)

Yeah. That's alright.

Leave the 40A breaker in the panel. Bring your 40A #6 aluminum wire out to the (new, I presume) "2 space subpanel" style disconnect.  Fit a 20A breaker there.

- Disconnect, check.
- <=50A breaker protecting #6 feeder, check.
- <=20A breaker protecting heat pump, check.
- Passes inspection without worry, check.

Comment: Simple and elegant, though I'd guess there probably IS already a disconnect there. But replacing it with a sub-panel if it's unfused solves this neatly. In the unlikely event that the old wiring has a neutral, you could even use a 4-space and cover the service outlet.

Comment: Yes, already have disconnect.  See comments under the original question.  Amazing that a whole subpanel is less than 2 connectors.